# Определение координат в Telegram Bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot, геолокация

Прошу помощи. Не могу получить координаты в телеграм боте.
Использую вот эту библиотеку [пыщ](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core)

Код следующий

```
$keyboard[] = [new Up\KeyboardButton(['text' => 'message', 'request_location' => true])];
$reply_markup = new Up\Keyboard([
                'keyboard' => $keyboard,
              ]);

$r = Bot\Request::sendMessage([ 'chat_id' => $this->chat_id, 'text' => 'now your can send!', 'reply_markup' => $reply_markup]);
```

В ответе нет ничего о location, хотя я очень ожидал увидеть там ее. Карта в чате с точкой появляется. Вообщем не понятно чего дальше делать то

Comment: А все вопрос снят. не в том месте ждал данные от геолокации